# Cannot connect anymore to local SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-authentication

Today I went to connect to my local database but I cannot connect anymore for unknown reasons. I typed in (local) and used Windows authentication like I always do yet I get this error.

> Cannot connect to localhost.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (.Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the SQL Server service running? To check, right-click on "My Computer" and choose "Manage..." From the tree on the left side of the window, choose "Services and Applications", then "Services". Look for the "SQL Server" service and see if it is in the "Started" status. If not, right-click on the service and choose "Start".

Comment: for some reason I have mssql express(even though I don't have installed- maybe came from visual studios???) and sqlserver. Only mssql express was started. Find it weird because the sqlserver one was set to automatic but was not started.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check that the service is set to automatic start. this way when you reboot, you won't have to start the service...

Comment: That's the weird thing. It was set to automatic start. Yet it was not started and I did reboot when I could not get logged in.

Comment: It keeps not starting even though it is automatic. It did it again today.

Comment: Are there any startup dependencies? right click the service -> dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem. My database is stored on an external hard disk, unfortunately I plugged it in after I started the computer.

I had to **restart** the computer, to connect again successfully. A logout was not enough.